# Passing variable into regex In Gatsby graphql query

Tags: javascript, regex, graphql, gatsby

I have the following query which is receiving the variable `$tag`. Currently I am filtering the results based on the value of its `frontmatter.keywords`. `keywords` is a comma separated string, so I need to use a regex to check for the inclusion of `$tag` within it, however I can't work out how to pass the variable into the regex. If I hardcode a value into the regex (as in the code below where I have hardcoded `/example/`, the filtering works. If I replace `example` with `$tag` I receive an Error:

> GraphQLError: Variable "$tag" is never used in operation "TagQuery".

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query TagQuery($tag: String) {
    allMarkdownRemark(
      limit: 100
      sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
      filter: { frontmatter: { keywords: { regex: "/example/" } } }
    ) {
      totalCount
      edges {
        node {
          fields {
            slug
          }
          excerpt
          frontmatter {
            title
            keywords
            date
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

How should I use `$tag` within the regex?

I'd actually prefer to take a different approach and add the tags as an array in `gatsby-node.js`, but there doesn't appear to be any way of filtering based on the value of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up splitting the tags into an array, then using the following to filter:

```
filter: { fields: { tags: { in: [$tag] } } }
```

Comment: can you tell me how you pass the variable $tag into query?

Comment: @OtaniShuzo The variables available in a query are the values you pass as keys to the  `context` object  when using `createPage()`. So if you use a context of `{alpha: 'abc', bravo: 2}`, you can access two variables (if you need to) in the query: `query ExampleQuery($alpha: String, $bravo: Int) {`

Comment: @Undistraction do you mind posting how the whole query looks like now?

Comment: @VasilisTsirimokos Here you go. Think this was it: https://github.com/Undistraction/gatsby-starter-skeleton/blob/master/src/components/templates/tag.js

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are passing $tag, just transform it to

```
const $tag = "\/".concat(tag).concat("\/")
```

But your error is specifically pointing to the fact that your query is not using the variable at all. So you'd also need to do

```
filter: { frontmatter: { keywords: { regex: $tag } } }
```